# Pi 2 - Debian (Noobs) Desktop missing

Tags: pi-2, noobs

I'm running a Rasp Pi 2 and i've had noobs installed for about 3 months.

Recently Restarted my pi, by going to  and shutdown then restart.

After the pi rebooted, I lost my desktop. 
I can Cntl+Alt+F1 to get to terminal.
When I right click on the desktop, i get 7 options.

- Terminal Emulator
- Web Browser
- Desktops > desktop 1 | add new desktop & remove last desktop
- ObConf
- Reconfigure
- Restart
- Exit

I've never seen this before. The only buttons that really do anything are Web Browser and Exit.

How do I get back to my desktop and why has this occurred?

PS. Please avoid suggesting formatting and reloading a new version of noobs, because I consider this a last resort.

Comment: Really no body? smh.

Comment: Did you do anything different/new on the last boot before it started doing this?

Comment: @patrickcook Not a single thing.

Comment: Hate to say it, but my guess is corrupted sd card.

Comment: @patrickcook if it's corrupted, Can't you overwrite some file, to fix the issue?

Comment: I'm a little confused NOOB appears as a list of things to have on your Pi as a single "dialogue" in the middle of the screen.  Your talk of using Cntl-Alt-F1 sounds like the keystrokes to switch from the GUI that Raspbian (and others I guess) Linux distributions to other (virtual) terminal screens which will present you with a Linux (text) console.  Those "right-click" (a.k.a. "context") menu items sound like things like a window manager put up - I am guessing here (if you can't tell!) but have you lost a lot of things from the screen like a "start button" + taskbar + system tray?

Comment: @slyeven I've lost all of it. I said "Desktop" Because those things consist of a Desktop (SB, TB, ST). Yes from what I understand Raspbian is basically Debian with modifications. But what I have mentioned is what I have to work with to fix the issue.

Comment: I was just wondering whether you had switched to a different window manager (not lightdm) and had something minimalist like twm - but I tried to get that to run and found it is not a simple option that might have got changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `lxpanel` has died! Whilst in the GUI run a "Terminal Emulator" and then try running `lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi &`.   If that restores the panel all well and good, if not post up the error messages that appear and lets see if that gives any ideas...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's too late, I already re-installed Noobs this morning. I really didn't think it would take this website 3 full days, and not to have an answer. I should of tried to Raspberry Pi forums instead. I'll upvote you for the effort.

Comment: The Pi I used is headless so I didn't get around to looking at this until I was doing something else that needed me to run the Xephyr XServer-in-a-XServer on my PC...